# angular JS refresh a http

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

i am trying to make an agenda with contacts and i just started learning AngularJS. So far i did a php that generates me a JSON, load it on angular controller and than show it on html.

This is the angular code

```
var Agenda = angular.module('Agenda', []);

Agenda.controller('Contacts', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('php/contacts.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.jsonContacts = data;
    });
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<section class="agenda" ng-app="Agenda">
        <ul ng-controller="Contacts">
            <li ng-repeat="contact in jsonContacts">
                <div class="col1">{{contact.contact_id}}</div>
                <div class="col2">{{contact.contact_firstname + ' ' + contact.contact_lastname}}</div>
                <div class="col3">{{contact.contact_phone}}</div>
                <div class="col4">{{contact.contact_email}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a>Refresh</a>
    </section>
```

So far so good but now i am trying to refresh the content of the list when i press on the Refresh and i have no idea how to do that. If i also did something wrong in this code please let me know.

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're more than half way there!  Here's a few slight tweaks to what you have that should do the trick.  Turn your `$http` call into a function that we can invoke repeatedly - `refresh()`:

```
Agenda.controller('Contacts', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.refresh = function() {
        $http.get('php/contacts.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.jsonContacts = data;
        });
    }

    // call it initially
    $scope.refresh();
});
```

And then simply use `ng-click` to call the new `refresh()` function that we added above:

```
<section class="agenda" ng-app="Agenda">
        <ul ng-controller="Contacts">
            <li ng-repeat="contact in jsonContacts">
                <div class="col1">{{contact.contact_id}}</div>
                <div class="col2">{{contact.contact_firstname + ' ' + contact.contact_lastname}}</div>
                <div class="col3">{{contact.contact_phone}}</div>
                <div class="col4">{{contact.contact_email}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <a ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</a>
    </section>
```

Comment: WOW this is simple yet amazing at the same time. Thank you very much, jandersen!